# String Length attribute in Realm for Xamarin C#

Tags: xamarin, attributes, realm, realm-net

In EF its `StringLength` and in `SQLite.net` its `MaxLength` but I cannot seem to figure out if there is an attribute for setting the Expected String Length in Realm.

Anyone know what it is?

Comment: from looking at their docs I don't see any obvious way to do this

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to state how long your strings will be with Realm. You can go ahead and store strings as long as you'd like, up to the maximum supported length of 16MB. If you need to store longer strings than that, you'll need to split them over multiple properties.